# Module Not Found Error inside virtual environment

Tags: python, django, pip, virtual-environment

I am working on a project inside virtual environment and suddenly I got this error:

```
(env) D:\django3_by_example\env\Scripts>pip install markdown3.2.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\django3_by_example\env\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

It was working fine till now and after a moment it gave me this error. I checked the path from 'where pip' command and it showed me it's installed inside virtual environment.

Comment: You can try: `python -m pip install <package_name>`. It might also worth trying to `deactivate` and `source` the virtual env again

Comment: I just tried but it gave me the same error 'no module named pip'.

Comment: Also be sure that you have included Python (not only pip) to windows PATH variable, then try to run `python -m ensurepip`.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Can you tell me why pip worked earlier but gave me this error now? Appreciate the help.